# Logic of SML recursive functions

Tags: recursion, smlnj

Hi I'm trying to learn SML. I'm having trouble understanding the some of the recursive functions I'm coming across , for example

```
 fun Square (x:int, y:int)=
if y=0 
then 1 
else x * Square(x,y-1);
```

I understand that in the else bracket the x is being multiplied by the value of the Square function taking x and y-1 as arguments and this process will continue until y hits 0 . I'm just not clear in each step of the recursion what is x being multiplied by? Furthermore once y hits 0 why doesn't the function return 1?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The function *does* return 1 when `y = 0`, but this value is returned to the caller - `Square(x,1)` - which returns a value to *its* caller, `Square(x,2)`, and so on.
(The big secret of recursive function is that they work exactly like non-recursive functions.)

I think one of the best ways towards understanding is to use the substitution method.

Look at `Square (3,2)`. Replacing `x` and `y` in the function definition with their values gives

```
if 2 = 0 then 1 else 3 * Square (3, 2-1)
```

2 is clearly not 0, so we need to figure out what `Square (3, 1)` is before we can continue with the multiplication.
Repeat the same process:

```
if 1 = 0 then 1 else 3 * Square (3, 1-1)
```

The condition is still false, so continue with `Square (3,0)`.

```
if 0 = 0 then 1 else 3 * Square (3, 0-1)
```

Now the condition is true, so we know that `Square (3,0)` is 1.
Move back one level and substitute:

```
if 1 = 0 then 1 else 3 * 1
```

So, `Square (3,1)`  is 3. Substitute again:

```
if 2 = 0 then 1 else 3 * 3
```

which makes 9, which is what you would expect.

You could also consider this (endless) sequence of non-recursive functions:

```
...
fun Square_3 (x, y) = if y = 0 then 1 else x * Square_2 (x, y-1)
fun Square_2 (x, y) = if y = 0 then 1 else x * Square_1 (x, y-1)
fun Square_1 (x, y) = if y = 0 then 1 else x * Square_0 (x, y-1)
fun Square_0 (x, y) = if y = 0 then 1 else x * Square_minus1(x, y-1)
fun Square_minus1 (x, y) = ...
```

and then think about how `Square_2(3, 2)` works. `Square(3,2)` works in exactly the same way.

(By the way, your function has a pretty odd name. You might want to rename it.)